# How to securely delete a file after it was insecurely deleted (in linux)

Tags: linux, forensics, deletion

How can I securely delete/shred a file after I accidentally deleted the file insecurely?

Let's say I have Debian Linux installed on a laptop with a 1000T spinning hard disk (so putting aside wear leveling uncertainty and `sfill`).

I stored some super-sensitive data to `secret.txt`. For some reason, I decided I wanted to delete this file, but I accidentally executed `rm secret.txt`.

Using `testdisk`, I can see the newly `unlink`ed file. I can restore the deleted file's contents using `testdisk`, but--afaik--that would just create a new *copy* of the file (so doing a restore -> shred may not securely wipe the original file's contents from the disk, and it may actually make the issue worse)

How can I actually `shred`/`srm` the blocks containing the original file contents of `secret.txt` following the accidental execution of `rm secret.txt`?

Comment: Since your question mentions an HDD, you can always fill the HDD with a random garbage file, then delete that.

Comment: Securely wiping files can be very difficult in many file systems, particularly journaling systems such as EXT4. That said, a pretty good but not 100 percent method is to write all or as much as possible unallocated space as was suggested by @MechMK1 then delete the file. Zeroes are faster than random, but either will work. In the correct partition: "dd if=/dev/zero of=bigtemp.dat" , then delete after you run out of space.

Comment: Note that this HDD fill method is comparable to what **shred** does. Actually it's better because it's not dependent upon in-place overwites like shred is, but it's time consuming.

Comment: Sorry, I explicitly stated that the disk was 1000T and asked to put aside `sfill`, which is a utility that fills the disk with random data. Surely, there must be some way to use `testdisk` or similar to find the exact location of the `unlink`ed original file, then pass that info to some other utility like `shred` or `srm` -- instructing it where to securely (over)write the data at the given location..

Comment: How about relinking it and then shredding? https://serverfault.com/questions/168909/relinking-a-deleted-file

Comment: @RedS This is a good idea; the question linked refers to the case where the deleted file is still open, so I don't think it's particularly helpful as no `/proc/<pid>/` dir would exist for the purposes of my question. Your comment begs the question: how can I extract the inode of a deleted file detected by `testdisk`, and how can `debugfs` help if the FS is ext3/4?

Comment: Perhaps you need to look at the code for testdisk to find out how it works and whether the relevant code can be linked so a new console tool can be made to help. Ideally testdisk would be updated to display the inode.

Comment: @Todd to this end I created a feature request for `testdisk` here https://github.com/cgsecurity/testdisk/issues/93